Mounting a TV on tongue & groove wooden wall
As far as I can tell there are no studs behind this wall, though maybe the finder I have is just not great with this material or I'm not using it properly, but in the event there really are no studs, is there a way to safely mount a modern ~35 pound TV here? Are the Tongue & Groove slats going to be strong enough to hold the mount and TV up?


They should be 1/2 inch thick or better and nailed(though the tongues) to the studs.
A magnet stud finder/compass should find the studs for best mounting, but the boards should be good enough.
They are not as weak as drywall.

So turns out there was indeed a stud (unsurprisingly where all the screw holes are). The roughness of the edges of the screw holes was causing the stud finder to miss the stud.

No studs? It's possible.  There are construction systems (eg Lockwood, log cabin) that just use planks and no studs. With these systems the wood will be thick enough to support your television.
Open up a light switch or electrical outlet to have a look inside the wall. These are usually mounted next to a stud in stud walls.
On the other hand 40 a pound television can surface mounted on drywall using Molys, or similar hollow-wall anchors,so even if there are studs it may not matter that you can't find therm.
